# How to cancel a blocking thread caused by input() in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, select, tcp

I'm starting to learn more about TCP protocols in Python and I've been having some trouble with blocking threads inside clients.

Ideally, my application would work like this: I have different clients with thread functions, each one of them containing an input function in order to receive a specific command to send to the server (for example 'X'). When the 'X' is tapped in ONE client, the server receives it and sends a message to all the other clients informing that the program will continue and releasing them from their input functions - almost like cancelling them.

The problem lies on the fact that the input functions are blocking the clients from leaving the loop. I've tried setting the input thread functions as daemon but it blocks until you tap something anyway - which is unfortunately the only workaround that I've found so far.

I would like to use `socket` and the `select` module for connection, without being attached to any particular OS (so no `msvcrt` that works on Windows or the `select` module to monitor the `stdin`, which is only available in UNIX based OS).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914294/5287638) help?

Comment: I think it would work but I was looking for a Python built-in module, so it may be exploitable by any user.