# Discord bot does not allow for user input via console without throwing error

Tags: python, discord.py

My friend and I are working on a project where if you run a single command, being a setup command, the user running the code can talk on Discord chat through the bot via sending messages from the console.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on ready():
    print("Logged in as {}".format(bot.user))
@bot.command()
async def setup(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    while True:
        msg = input("Message to send: ")
        ctx.send(msg)
```

The problem with this is that it throws an error,

```
Loop thread traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bobot\OneDrive\Documents\projs\py\penissie.py", line 128, in <module>
    bot.run(token)
  File "C:\Users\bobot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Users\bobot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
  File "C:\Users\bobot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "C:\Users\bobot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 640, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\bobot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 321, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\bobot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 607, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\bobot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1922, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Users\bobot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\bobot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bobot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1395, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "C:\Users\bobot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1392, in process_commands
    await self.invoke(ctx)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\bobot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\bobot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\bobot\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bobot\OneDrive\Documents\projs\py\cool.py", line 48, in setup
    msg = input("Message to send: ")
```

which I believe may mean that the bot cannot run its loop while I am in an input statement

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

### Why doesn't this work?

The `input()` function is *not* asynchronous. This means that it "pauses" the rest of your program. Because of how Discord works, your bot has to send requests every once in a while to keep your bot online. So, because the input is not asynchronous, it doesn't work.

### What can we do to make it work?

There are other libraries that allow you to take input from the console asynchronously. For example, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901813/asyncio-server-and-client-to-handle-input-from-console) they use the library [aioconsole](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aioconsole). This library has a the function `aioconsole.ainput()` which achieves exactly what we want.

### For your example

You use a `while True` loop here. This is definitely not recommended. In asynchronous programming, this would also stop your bot as well. [In the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429306/run-async-while-loop-independently) they use `asyncio.ensure_future(function())` to run a loop with async.

In the [asyncio documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future) it says that:

> Future objects are used to bridge low-level callback-based code with high-level async/await code.

Even though you can use an awaitable object for this function, for this example we won't be using that.

*note, the following code may or may not work because I am not at my PC at the moment to test it. When I get home, I'll fix any bugs*

```py
import asyncio
import aioconsole

def loop(ctx):
    while True:
        msg = aioconsole.ainput("Message to send: ")
        ctx.send(msg)
        if msg.upper() == "CANCEL":
            break  # break loop if cancel is typed in all caps

    

@bot.command()
async def setup(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(loop(ctx))
```

The following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016501/how-to-schedule-and-cancel-tasks-with-asyncio) also explains this really well.

Comment: Thank you, but the input was my main problem, for some reason the while True loop does not do anything to my bot.

Comment: @Xenan I covered that in my post

Comment: @Xenan Turns out, I forgot to cover that part in the example code. I updated it accordingly.